# ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=30000]

Tags: errors, memory

Below is part of my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=1cm, inner=2.1cm,twoside, headsep=16pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\+}{\discretionary{\mbox{${\bm\cdot}\mkern-1mu$}}{}{}}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{varwidth} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=5pt,font=footnotesize}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\singlespacing
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{keyval}% http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval
\makeatletter
\newlength{\mylist@beforeskip}
\newlength{\mylist@afterskip}

\define@key{mylist}{beforeskip}{\setlength{\mylist@beforeskip}{#1}}
\define@key{mylist}{afterskip}{\setlength{\mylist@afterskip}{#1}}
\newenvironment{mylist}[1][,]
 {\setkeys{mylist}{beforeskip=10pt,afterskip=10pt,#1}%
\par\vspace*{\mylist@beforeskip}%
\begin{itemize}}
{\end{itemize}%
\vspace*{\mylist@afterskip}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{etoolbox,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,graphicx}
\newcommand{\addstufftotoc}[2][toc]{% \addimagetotoc[<toc>]{<stuff>}
\addtocontents{#1}{#2}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}% <cmd>
{\begingroup}% <search>
{\begingroup\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% <replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{cnt}
\newcommand\textlist{}
\newcommand\settext[2]{%
\csdef{text#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\addtext[1]{%
\stepcounter{cnt}%
\csdef{text\thecnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\gettext[1]{%
\csuse{text#1}}
\newcounter{colnum}
\newcommand\maketabularrow[1]{%
\setcounter{colnum}{0}%
\whileboolexpr
{ test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{#1}} }%
 {&\stepcounter{colnum}\thecolnum}
}
%   
\def\hlinewd#1{%
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 %
\futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline} 
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=0pt,leftmargin=0, rightmargin=0, linecolor=gray,outerlinewidth=.1, innerleftmargin=0, innerrightmargin=0, innertopmargin=0,innerbottommargin=0, everyline = true, splittopskip=.6cm, splitbottomskip=.3cm] 
\end{mdframed} 
\small 
\leavevmode 
\newline 
\leavevmode 
\newline 
\scriptsize  
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}AAA} 
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[trim=0.6cm 4.5cm 0cm 1cm, clip=true,width=1.0\linewidth]{./tmp/AAA.pdf}\par} 
\leavevmode 
\newline 
\\ 
} 
\newpage 

\end{document}linecolor=goldenpoppy
```

I got this error message.

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 295--307


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 323
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=30000].
\par ->\@restorepar 
                \everypar {}\par \@endpefalse 
l.329 ..../tmp/image.pdf}\par}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I found many replies for the similar question but none of the answer solve my pblm.

Comment: You have posted 37 questions so you should know that providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) increases your changes of getting an answer.

Comment: Yes, I know but pblm is with my large chunk of code. I could not figure out why this pblm is. I attempted to copy a part of it but that works fine.

Comment: @user15662 Although everyone faces the same kind problems while creating [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and debugging LaTeX code. **Building Up** and **Hacking Down** are two [valid approaches](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl).

Comment: @texenthusiast, i have just posted my pblm (edited)

Comment: @user15662 the code you posted doesn't compile, as an mwe should.  what's more, it doesn't have 329 lines, so the error message must come from compiling something else.  it's clear what your problem is (recursive definition), but without a compilable example, it's impossible to provide a resolution.

Comment: @user15662 _you_ need to take the posted code and remove all packages that are not needed. That is if you can make the error without that package, remove it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I couldn't give you more than +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table of contents is typeset as a list, where `\par` has not its primitive meaning.

Change the definition of `\addstufftotoc` into

```
\newcommand{\addstufftotoc}[2][toc]{% \addimagetotoc[<toc>]{<stuff>}
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{\nobreak\smallskip#2\par\medskip}}%
  }%
}
```

and use it as

```
\addstufftotoc{\includegraphics[trim=0.6cm 4.5cm 0cm 1cm,
  clip=true,width=1.0\linewidth]{./tmp/AAA.pdf}}
```

which saves you from the burden of adding fixed formatting instructions in `\addstufftotoc`.

Comment: Why do we need two `\unexpanded` here?

Comment: @cjorssen Because `\addtocontents` writes to the `.aux` file and then the entry is written to the `.toc` file at the end of the job, when the `.aux` file is closed and read in.